# Can i publish Sharepoint Apps if my Office 365 Subscription uses Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, app

I have a paid office365 account which was created a while back.  The sharepoint version is 2010 because when the account was created this was the latest version of sharepoint.

I have an Sharepoint 2013 app which i want to deploy to the app store.  I have read that i must have a developer site collection to publish the app.

Is this only available on Office365 with Sharepoint 2013?

What other options do i have other than upgrading to 2013?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/apps/dn146012.aspx

Comment: I am creating a Sharepoint Hosted App

Comment: Apps are 2013 only, so you will need to upgrade 365 to 2013